# Slow inserts via python script even its just 400 rows

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, azure-sql-database

I have a "dataframe" of 400 rows.

When I try to push the data to SQL Server (on azure VM), its taking about 4 minutes for an insert.

Below is the `exceutemany` statement I am using:

```
cursor.executemany(insert_query,df)
```

I am aware that `cursor.executemany` does row by row insert but for just 400 rows its a bit strange for it to be taking 4 minutes.

Could you please help me, as in, what I can do to troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Think this is an issue from pymssql. here's a link to issue listed on github https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql/issues/332. 
According to one of the comment, there is a workaround using `fast_executemany` https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql/issues/332#issuecomment-472371207

Comment: Hi Hue,If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer or vote it. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: @LeonYue : yes, Fast_exexcutemany has definitely reduced the time to insert.

Comment: @Hue I'm glad my answer could be helpful. Can you think about accept(mark) it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please reference this document [Pyodbc Cursor](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor)`.
 You can [executemany(sql, *params), with fast_executemany=True](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#executemanysql-params-with-fast_executemanytrue).

Executes the SQL statement for the entire set of parameters, returning None. The single params parameter must be a sequence of sequences, or a generator of sequences.

```
params = [ ('A', 1), ('B', 2) ]
cursor.fast_executemany = True
cursor.executemany("insert into t(name, id) values (?, ?)", params)
```

Here, all the parameters are sent to the database server in one bundle (along with the SQL statement), and the database executes the SQL against all the parameters as one database transaction. Hence, this form of executemany() should be much faster than the default executemany(). However, there are limitations to it, see [fast_executemany](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Features-beyond-the-DB-API#fast_executemany) for more details.

Please modify your code and test again:

```
cursor.fast_executemany = True
cursor.executemany(insert_query,df)
```

Hope this helps.